# Ruby on Rails: Avoiding infinite loop when calling .save during an update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, infinite-loop

I have an order model that `has_many :items`. Each item has `item.price` for the cost of said item. I want to add up all of the item prices in the order for a `order.total_price`. Right now I'm doing that with

```
after_save :update_total_price, :if => "self.saved.nil? "


def update_total_price
     self.total_price = Item.find(item_ids).inject(0){|sum,item| sum + (item.price * item.amount) } #amount is how many items there are
     self.saved = 1
     self.save if self.saved
end
```

This works just fine the first time that I put in the info, but if I try to edit the order, the total_price doesn't get updated because `update_total_price` doesn't get called because self.saved is not nil.

What can I do to make it so that updating the model will update it, but won't keep on doing an infinite loop of calling `.save`?

Answer (score 6):

Why not have the update_total_price NOT save the data again.

just set the value in before_update:

```
before_save :update_total_price

def update_total_price
  self.total_price = items.find(:all).inject(0){|sum,item| sum + (item.price * item.amount) } 
end
```

Comment: This works wonderfully. Thanks. I had totally forgotten about before_save

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work because `Item.find(item_ids)` expects the items' ids, but they haven't been created yet, so this causes an error. How could I make it work?

Comment: Just add a check on item_ids.

Comment: I don't know what you mean :\

Comment: when are the id's created? on the initial save?

Comment: I believe so. But when the Item.find(item_ids) is called, it errors and says you can't find without an ID. I'm guessing that it trys to get the Item before it creates them.

Comment: If it helps, item is a nested object inside order with a has_many association.

Comment: rather than Item.find you can just use entries.find(:all)

Comment: sorry, items.find or items.all - working on something else and have entries on the brain.

Comment: It seems you don't have the `have_many :items` relation defined in your order model. I guess you need to add that, and use the `items` instead of the `Item.find(item_ids)`. Mind you: that is a weird id-name, i would expect the `Item` to have an `order_id` column.

Comment: @nathanvda I do have the correct association setup and items does have an `order_id` column.

@toby-hede items.all works the second time around I submit the form. It doesn't calculate the total price when I create a new order, only when I update it. It also doesn't work if I try and update it more than once.

Answer (score 1):

```
after_save :update_total_price

def update_total_price          
   self.total_price = find_total_price
   self.save_without_callbacks
end

def find_total_price
  Item.find(item_ids).inject(0){|sum,item| sum + (item.price * item.amount) 
end
```

Comment: This will cause another infinite loop. The save(false) avoids validations, but not callbacks.

Comment: Oops. How about the above edit? Actually Toby's answer is better but I'll leave this here anyway.